# How can i load image to JLabel using JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

This are my packages.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

Im trying to load an image into the JLabel using JFileChooser from other function. Im trying to return the image because somehow my file chooser cannot load image in  JLabel.

```
GraphologyAnalysis() here is declaration of my pane.
public GraphologyAnalysis()  
{
    super("Graphology Analysis");
    setSize(width,height);
    Container pane= getContentPane();
    pane.setBackground(Color.white); 
    pane.setLayout(null);

    displayImg= new JLabel (new ImageIcon ("How to return in an image in this?"));
    displayImg.setSize(580,310);
    displayImg.setLocation(480,150);
    pane.add(displayImg);
```

This function below is from JFileChooser. File chooser somehow not load the image.

```
private BufferedImage imgUp;
public void showfile() throws java.io.IOException 
{
    File("C:/Users/User/Pictures/Vita Wallpaper"));
    JFileChooser temp = new JFileChooser();
    temp.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    int result = temp.showOpenDialog(this);

    File file = new File("C:/Users/User/Pictures");

    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        file = temp.getSelectedFile();
        imgUp = ImageIO.read(file);
        displayImg=new JLabel (new ImageIcon (imgUp));
        displayImg.setSize(580,310);
        displayImg.setLocation(480,150);
        add(displayImg);
    }
```

Comment: Don't create a **NEW** `displayImg` JLabel. Instead simply change the icon displayed in the current `displayImg` JLabel, the one already added to your GUI. Call `setIcon(...)` on it. If this doesn't work, then you should post a valid [mcve].

Comment: Thank you very much. Its work. Finally I can insert the image.